# Check for existence of value in firebase realtime database?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using V9 (modular) version of Firebase realtime database. I have a list of URLs with auto-generated keys using `push()`. This is the data structure.

[image]

What I want is to check for the existence of one of these url's in the list. Here's what I've attempted.

```
    const testURL = "https://i.redd.it/bm6psl9sgsj81.png"; //First one in the list
    const db = getDatabase();
    const dbRef = ref(db, "burnedURLs/");
    const q = query(dbRef, equalTo(testURL));
    const snapshot = await get(q);
    const results = snapshot.toJSON();
    console.log(results); //Returns NULL
```

How does one check the existence of a value, or just retrieve a value when you don't know the key? The documentation for V9 isn't very good and most examples I've found are for V8. Thanks for any help.

Edit: Using `exists()` returns false when it does exist (It's the first child in the tree). I think the issue is that I'm not forming the query correctly and that's what I need help with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `get(<query>)` returns a [DataSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/database.datasnapshot.md) that still has [`exists()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/database.datasnapshot.md#datasnapshotexists) which returns `true` if this `DataSnapshot` contains any data.:

```
const q = query(dbRef, orderByValue(), equalTo(testURL));

const snapshot = await get(q);

if (snapshot.exists()) {
  const results = snapshot.val();
  console.log('Results', results)
} else {
  console.log('Data does not exist')
}
```

From the documentation,

> To filter data, you can combine any of the limit or range methods with an order-by method when constructing a query.

So adding `orderByValue()` in query should solve the issue.

Comment: I tried `exists()` but it returns false. That's the problem is that the data does exist and I think I'm forming my query incorrectly.

Comment: @JosephToronto you need to add `orderByValue()` in your query. From the docs, _To filter data, you can combine any of the limit or range methods with an order-by method when constructing a query._ Also you'll have to add `burnedURLs: { ".indexOn": ".value" }` in your security rules.